# python requests link headers

Tags: python, hyperlink, header, python-requests

I'm trying to find best way to capture links listed under response headers, exactly like this one and I'm using python requests module. Below is link which has Link Headers section on Python Requests page:
docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

But, in my case my response headers contains links like below:

```
{'content-length': '12276', 'via': '1.1 varnish-v4', 'links': '<http://justblahblahblah.com/link8.html>;rel="last">,<http://justblahblahblah.com/link2.html>;rel="next">', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding, Origin'}
```

Please notice > after "last" which is not the case under Requests examples and I just cant seem to figure out how to solve this.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Apologize if I wasn't clear, but I want to know how I can get Next and last link from response using rel in header response.

Comment: If requests do not work with this `link` header then you can parse it manually: it is not that hard.

Comment: Use request's parsing function as a reference. See https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/f5dacf84468ab7e0631cc61a3f1431a32e3e143c/requests/utils.py#L580

Comment: actually Im already doing that now, using re and looking for pattern.  First, I'm parsing links exact links and then looking for page value(above links are just examples).  But I guess I should rather look for pattern with link and rel

Comment: ahh thanks for the link to parsing function, I see how its done.  I can definitely use this.  Thanks for your help Alik.

Comment: I think 'links' should be 'link' (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Link)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can parse the header's value manually. To make things easier you might want to use request's parsing function [`parse_header_links`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/f5dacf84468ab7e0631cc61a3f1431a32e3e143c/requests/utils.py#L580) as a reference.

Or you can do some find/replace and use original `parse_header_links`

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: d = {'content-length': '12276', 'via': '1.1 varnish-v4', 'links': '<http://justblahblahblah.com/link8.html>;rel="last">,<http://justblahblahblah.com/link2.html>;rel="next">', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding, Origin'}

In [3]: requests.utils.parse_header_links(d['links'].rstrip('>').replace('>,<', ',<'))
Out[3]:
[{'rel': 'last', 'url': 'http://justblahblahblah.com/link8.html'},
 {'rel': 'next', 'url': 'http://justblahblahblah.com/link2.html'}]
```

If there might be a space or two between `>,` and `<` then you need to do replace with a regular expression.

Comment: this is perfect for my case.

Comment: Next answer, using `response.links` is the right thing to use.

Answer (score 105):

There is already a way provided by `requests` to access links header

```
response.links
```

It returns the dictionary of links header value which can easily parsed further using

```
response.links['next']['url']
```

to get the required values.

Comment: You can also check for a link by using `if 'url' in response.links.get('next'):` first.

Comment: @cjbarth - `if response.links.get('next'):` worked better for me as it did not exist.

Comment: @westondeboer it can not be the answer since it doesn't solve OP's problem :-) Notice that OP asked about a very specific case that is not covered by requests builtin feature